# How to receive sqlcmd request and send response as base64 pdf by jasper report dependency

Tags: jasper-reports

I have written a rough program where the goal of this program is to be a program that has the ability to receive requests. The language that requests is SQL cmd and sends the request to the PostgreSQL database and sends the response as data that comes from the PostgreSQL database and then takes the data. Insert or stuff in jrxml file and then convert to base64 PDF at the end,
which I have tried to write and an error has occurred since the word start generate.

Programs used: eclipse, spring boot 3 and above and Java 17, 21, PostgreSQL database.

**Error**

```
[2m2024-01-18T15:35:33.425+07:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed initialization in 2 ms
start generate
[2m2024-01-18T15:35:34.012+07:00[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m32224[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Class not found when loading object from file: C:\Users\Teamking\eclipse-workspace\Npdf\target\classes\pdf.jasper.] with root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.ReportExpressionEvaluationData
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:773) ~[na:na]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.java:89) ~[jasperreports-6.12.2.jar:6.12.2-75c5e90a222ab406e416cbf590a5397028a52de3]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2034) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1898) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2224) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1733) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$FieldValues.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:2606) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2457) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2257) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1733) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$FieldValues.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:2606) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2457) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2257) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1733) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:467) ~[na:na]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:140) ~[jasperreports-6.12.2.jar:6.12.2-75c5e90a222ab406e416cbf590a5397028a52de3]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:116) ~[jasperreports-6.12.2.jar:6.12.2-75c5e90a222ab406e416cbf590a5397028a52de3]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.getReportSource(JasperFillManager.java:1105) ~[jasperreports-6.12.2.jar:6.12.2-75c5e90a222ab406e416cbf590a5397028a52de3]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:652) ~[jasperreports-6.12.2.jar:6.12.2-75c5e90a222ab406e416cbf590a5397028a52de3]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:1020) ~[jasperreports-6.12.2.jar:6.12.2-75c5e90a222ab406e416cbf590a5397028a52de3]
    at com.example.demo.service.ReportGenerateService.generate(ReportGenerateService.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.controller.ExportPDFpart1Controller.exportReportFromJrxml(ExportPDFpart1Controller.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:262) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:917) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:829) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) ~[na:na]
```

**Here is my code:**

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Npdf</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Npdf</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.12.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**ExportJRRequest**

```
package com.example.demo.bean;

public class ExportJRRequest {
    
    private String sqlCommand;
    
    public String getSqlCommand() {
        return sqlCommand;
    }

    public void setSqlCommand(String sqlCommand) {
        this.sqlCommand = sqlCommand;
    }

}
```

**ExportJRResponse**

```
package com.example.demo.bean;

public class ExportJRResponse {
    
    private String pdfBase64;

    public String getPdfBase64() {
        return pdfBase64;
    }

    public void setPdfBase64(String pdfBase64) {
        this.pdfBase64 = pdfBase64;
    }
    
}
```

**ExportPDFpart1Controller**

```
package com.example.demo.controller;
    
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.bean.ExportJRRequest;
import com.example.demo.bean.ExportJRResponse;
import com.example.demo.model.EmployeeModel;
import com.example.demo.service.InquiryService;
import com.example.demo.service.ReportGenerateService;

import net.sf.jasperreports.repo.ReportCompiler;
    
@RestController
@RequestMapping("export")
public class ExportPDFpart1Controller {
    
    @Autowired
    private InquiryService inquiryService;
    
    @Autowired
    private ReportGenerateService reportGenerateService;
    
    
    @PostMapping(path ="/part1")
    public @ResponseBody ExportJRResponse exportReportFromJrxml( @RequestBody ExportJRRequest req) throws Exception {
        
        ExportJRResponse res = new ExportJRResponse();
        
        //1
        List<EmployeeModel> data = inquiryService.executeEmployeeQuery(req.getSqlCommand());
        
        //2
        String base64 = reportGenerateService.generate(data);
        
        res.setPdfBase64(base64);
        
        return res;
    }
}
```

**EmployeeModel**

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class EmployeeModel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long empid;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "salary")
    private String salary;
    
    @Column(name = "dept")
    private String dept;
    
    @Column(name = "position")
    private String position;
    
    public EmployeeModel() {
        super();
    }
    
    public EmployeeModel(long empid, String name, String salary, String dept, String position) {
        super();
        this.empid = empid;
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.dept = dept;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public long getEmpid() {
        return empid;
    }

    public void setEmpid(long empid) {
        this.empid = empid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(String salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public String getDept() {
        return dept;
    }

    public void setDept(String dept) {
        this.dept = dept;
    }

    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }


}
```

**EmployeeRepository**

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.example.demo.model.EmployeeModel;



public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<EmployeeModel, Long> {
    
    List<EmployeeModel> findAll();
    
}
```

**InquiryService**

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.model.EmployeeModel;

import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.Query;

@Service
public class InquiryService {
    
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    public List<EmployeeModel> executeEmployeeQuery(String sql) {
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql, EmployeeModel.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

}
```

**ReportGenerateService**

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils;

import com.example.demo.model.EmployeeModel;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;

@Service
public class ReportGenerateService {
    
    
    public String generate(List<EmployeeModel> data ) throws FileNotFoundException, JRException  {
        System.out.println("start generate");
        String sourceFileName = ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.CLASSPATH_URL_PREFIX + "pdf.jasper").getAbsolutePath();
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(data);
        Map parameters = new HashMap();
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(sourceFileName, parameters, beanColDataSource);
        byte[] bPdf = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
        return  Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bPdf);
        
    }
    
}
```

It seems that after I updated the report runner to version 6.13.0, a new problem occurred after running instead.
error

```
2024-01-19T11:20:58.221+07:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2140[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
[2m2024-01-19T11:20:58.270+07:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m2140[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36morg.hibernate.orm.deprecation           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH90000025: PostgreSQLDialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
[2m2024-01-19T11:20:59.522+07:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2140[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
[2m2024-01-19T11:20:59.582+07:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2140[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2024-01-19T11:20:59.680+07:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m2140[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mJpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration[0;39m [2m:[0;39m spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
[2m2024-01-19T11:21:00.425+07:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2140[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path ''
[2m2024-01-19T11:21:00.437+07:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2140[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.example.demo.NpdfApplication        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started NpdfApplication in 5.392 seconds (process running for 6.293)
[2m2024-01-19T11:21:22.373+07:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2140[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2024-01-19T11:21:22.373+07:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2140[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2024-01-19T11:21:22.376+07:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2140[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed initialization in 3 ms
start generate
[2m2024-01-19T11:21:22.654+07:00[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m2140[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [pdf.jasper] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:178) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at com.example.demo.service.ReportGenerateService.generate(ReportGenerateService.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.controller.ExportPDFpart1Controller.exportReportFromJrxml(ExportPDFpart1Controller.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:262) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:917) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:829) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) ~[na:na]
```

Please give me some advice as this is my first time starting this job, and this is my project plan that needs to be done. Currently, I need to complete the API in part number 1 as shown in the picture:

[image]

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.ReportExpressionEvaluationData` is pretty clear. You seem to be missing part of JasperReports.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace indicates that you use jasperreports-6.12.2.jar to run the report, but the compiled report (*.jasper file) references net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.ReportExpressionEvaluationData which was introduced in JasperReports 6.13.0.

You need to make sure that the JasperReports version used to run the report is the same or newer than the version used to produce the compiled report.